# How to overcome AssociationTypeMismatch from NilClass error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model like this:

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :sale_items
```

I'm saving each item from sale_item at time.

There're some cases where no sale_item is saved and I got:

```
sale.sale_items = create_sale_items
```

But the value returned from the function is something like `[nil, nil, nil]`

And it throws the error `SaleItem(#70332578775280) expected, got NilClass(#70332514236280)`

How can I overcome that?

My create_sale_items is where `sale_items_form` represent the form that save each item

```
def create_sale_items
  sale_items_form.map do |sale_item|
    sale_item if sale_item.valid?
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the `create_sale_items` method?

Comment: so that method still outputs a value for each element in `sale_items_form`, but puts nil if it is not valid, which I assume is not what you want. You want to use `select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is that the `create_sale_items` method returns a value for each element in `sale_items_form` no matter what. In fact, it returns `nil` if the value is not valid, which does not make sense.

In order to only have it return valid values, you might want to use `select` instead with the same condition in the block.

```
def create_sale_items
  sale_items_form.select {|sale_item| sale_item.valid? }
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That's where I got stuck!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your `sale_item`'s are not valid, thus this code returns nil for each no valid item. Check that your items are valid.

```
def create_sale_items
  sale_items_form.map do |sale_item|
    sale_item if sale_item.valid? # else nil !!!
  end
end
```

Also as suggested for others, you should use `.select` instead of `.map` to filter the valid items.